# Breakups - Makeups

Tags: expressions

I came across this expression:

> Frequent breakups and makeups

Is the "makeups" associated with the state after someone copes with the "breakups"?

Answer (score 6):

In this case makeup means getting back together after a breakup, finishing arguing and apologizing to each other.

Comment: Yes, but it might be spelled "make-up", to distinguish it from cosmetics.

Comment: Or even "make up", without the hyphen.

Answer (score 4):

> Is the "makeups" associated with the state after someone copes with the "breakups"?

Yes. Adding to @Tymek Wojnarowski's answer (+1), just a note that a related phrasal verb, '[make up for x](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/make-up-for)' doesn't "require" breakups.